# A differential equation that needs some algebra

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

I have a differential equation: $$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(x \cos\theta +y \sin\theta)+k(x \cos\theta +y \sin\theta)=\theta'(y \cos\theta-x \sin\theta)$$
where $x, y, \theta$ are all unknown functions of time, while $k$ is constant.

So this equation is of the form $$y'+ky=f(t)$$ if I could express the right hand side of this equation in terms of $y$ and $y'$ then I will be able to solve it analytically for $y(t)$, I think it might be possible by a little algebraic manipulation, but I don't know how, I would appreciate any help.
Edit: $\theta'$ can be considered constant of known value.

Comment: @Evgeny The result would be $x'cos\theta+y'sin\theta=-k(xcos\theta+ysin\theta)$, actually that was the previous step, I got here from there, but this can't be solved.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken in my previous comment. However, it's not quite right when you have *three* unknown functions and only *one* equation.

Comment: @Evgeny Never mind, yes I know what you mean, but it is OK here since I am interested in $xcos\theta+ysin\theta$ as a whole as a single function of time.

Comment: Okay. But maybe you could show your starting point and there is a way other than that leads to this equation?

Comment: Set $z=x\cos \theta + y\sin\theta$. The equation reads $z'+kz=\theta ' \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} z$. I wonder if this leads to something

Comment: @user160738 I will check if it can help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set $$z = x\cos \left(θ\right) + y\sin \left(θ\right)$$

Then,

$$\frac{dz}{dθ} = y\cos \left(θ \right)- x\sin \left(θ\right)$$

So, the given expression becomes,

$$ \frac{dz}{dt} + kz = \frac{dθ}{dt} . \frac{dz}{dθ}$$

Now, simplifying the RHS using the chain rule, 
$$ \frac{dz}{dt} + kz = \frac{dz}{dt} $$

Simplifying, 
$$ kz = 0 $$

$$ y = -x \cot \left(θ\right) $$

Comment: why did you integrate? you could have eliminated $\frac{dz}{dt}$ from both sides of the equation $\frac{dz}{dt} + kz = \frac{dz}{dt}$

Comment: Your answer would be correct if $\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}$ is used instead of the ordinary differential operator in this equation$\frac{dz}{dt} + kz = \frac{d\theta}{dt} . \frac{dz}{d\theta}$, but is it right then that $ \frac{d\theta}{dt} . \frac{\partial z}{\partial\theta}=\frac{dz}{dt}$

Comment: @KamelIsaac, I am pretty sure that $\frac{d\theta}{dt}.\frac{dz}{d\theta} = \frac{dz}{dt} $ even if the normal differential operator is used. But I should not have integrated, I'll fix that.

Comment: The question is: Is it legal that $\frac{d\theta}{dt} . \frac{\partial z}{\partial\theta}=\frac{dz}{dt}$, note the partial derivative operator